# Is loading triggered from the click of a submit button generated by h:commandButton a full load?

Tags: jsf

A jsf page contains a form with a `commandButton` element like `<h:commandButton action="#{bean.search}"`. This `submit` button will trigger a bean, which then will send more data back to this same jsf page.

Question: after the submit, is the jsf page fully loaded again? or is just the part containing the newly retrieved data reload and other parts are not loaded again?

Answer (score 0):

By default JSF will fully reload the page. This can be tested by looking at the browser network developer tools while submitting the `commandButton`. If you intend to only render a part of the page - e.g. a label that outputs the result - you can do that by using AJAX.

For example if your `commandButton` is in a form, by adding

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form:result"  />
```

within your `commandButton` tag, you can specify that only the contents of the form are processed by the server and only the label with the ID 'result' is rendered.

For further information take a look at this guide for AJAX in JSF: https://www.beyondjava.net/a-comprehensive-guide-to-jsf-ajax

You will see that the author shows the full page loading without AJAX.

Alternatively here is the official documentation for `<f:ajax>`:
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/vdldoc/f/ajax.html